# Compare 2 object arrays in java, perform condition and modify list data?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, compare

I have 2 lists in java, and I need to validate when there is a match, I set a field of the first list, I tried to do it with streams, but I don't know how to compare the two lists, list don't have same kind of elements I want to do something like this:

```
public static List<TransactionalityIdDBDTO> getVariationDateRange(List<TransactionalityIdDBDTO> list1,
                                                                      List<TransactionalityIdDBDTO> list2){
        List<TransactionalityIdDBDTO> idDBDTOS= new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator prueba=list1.iterator();

        while(prueba.hasNext()){
            TransactionalityIdDBDTO transactionalityIdDBDTO=(TransactionalityIdDBDTO) prueba.next();
            if(transactionalityIdDBDTO.get_id().equals(list2.get_id())){
                transactionalityIdDBDTO.setVariation("1232");
                idDBDTOS.add(transactionalityIdDBDTO);
            }
        }
        return idDBDTOS;
    }
```

Clase TransactionalityIdDBDTO

```
public class TransactionalityIdDBDTO extends AbstractDTO {
    private TransactionalityDBDTO _id;
    private String totalTransaction;
    private List<String> idResult;
    private String variation;
```

Comment: What is `list2.get_id()` supposed to mean?

Comment: `list2.get_id()` It's a String

Comment: `List` has no such method. If you're trying to find an element in the list, you'll need to iterate over it.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare lists using equals. e.g

```
list1.equals(list2);
```

However,

- order is important.  If lists contain the same content but in different order they will be considered unequal.
- the objects the lists hold must override `equals`.  The criteria for what constitutes two objects of  `TransactionalityIdDBDTO` to be equal are up to you.  Based on your code, it seems that `id` is a good start.
- if you plan on using those objects as keys in a map, you must override `hashCode` too (it's a good idea to do this anyway).
- if the lists are not in order but you want to consider them equal, then you should probably sort them first based on the id.  You can do that like this.

```
list1.sort(Comparator.comparing(TransTransactionalityIdDBDTO::get_id));
list2.sort(Comparator.comparing(TransTransactionalityIdDBDTO::get_id));
```

Objects like `String, Integer, and other wrapper classes` implement `Comparable` which means they can be compared to each other of the same type using the above.  But instead of `get_id` which returns a `String`, say you had get `get_Foo`.  Then the `Foo class` would need to implement comparable or you would have to provide a more detailed comparator on which to sort.

There are many examples of Comparing objects on the site.  I recommend you search them using the `[hashCode]`, `[equals]`, `[comparable]` and `[comparator]` tags.  Imo, understanding these and how they work are essential for a reasonable working knowledge of Java.